# Element with same name

Tags: html, css

i have this problem with css.All i want is to declare to css an element  with the same name.

for example there is a p class with the name .element1
and a div with the same name. Is there an option to different them,but keeping the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the multiple class selector.

```
<p class='element1 paragraph'>paragraph</p>
<p class='element1 paragraph2'>paragraph</p>

<div class='element1 divClass'>paragraph</div>
<div class='element1 divClass2'>paragraph</div>
```

css

```
.element1.paragraph{
color:red;
}

.element1.paragraph2{
color:blue;
}

.element1.divClass{
background:gray;
}
.element1.divClass2{
background:yellow;
}
```

This way all of the element have the same class name, but they can still be singled out individually by css, using another class name that identifies them individually. This is possible because html allows elements to have MULTIPLE class names.

Answer (score 0):

```
p.element1 {
 /* style here */
}
div.element1 {
 /* style here */
}
```

- http://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/

Comment: and if is more than one div?

Comment: @StratosAsimis Than you have to make a difference (add another class `div.class1.class2`, id `div.class1#id1` and so on) or use parent of the element `.parent div.class1` or `.parent > div.class1`.

Comment: Parent? how can i do that